# Why doesn't Select() convert a IEnumerable<dynamic> to IEnumerable<StrongType>?

Tags: c#, linq, dapper

I'm trying to use Dapper simply to map my database tables to types in C#, however, some of my types need additional elements that are not in the table.  To do this I am using a factory that can take column values and set the appropriate properties.

```
public IEnumerable<IMyType> All() {
  var query = _connection.Query("SELECT * FROM [table]");
  return query.Select(o => _myTypeFactory.Create(o));
}
```

Currently this is resulting the return statement generating an error:

*Cannot convert expression type `'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<dynamic>'` to return type `'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<IMyType>'`*

My factory class looks something like this:

```
public class MyTypeFactory {
  public IMyType Create(dynamic o) {
    return Create((String) o.Code, (Int32) o.KeyID);
  }
  public IMyType Create(String code, Int32 keyID) {
    return new MyType(code, Cache.Lookup(keyID));
  }
}
```

Why doesn't the `Select()` method return `IEnumerable<IMyType>`?  What do I need to do to make this work? Is this just the wrong approach and there's a better way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simplest fix is just to use the `Cast<>` LINQ operator:

```
public IEnumerable<IMyType> All() {
  var query = _connection.Query("SELECT * FROM [table]");
  return query.Select(o => _myTypeFactory.Create(o))
              .Cast<IMyType>();
}
```

Alternatively, you could cast each element:

```
public IEnumerable<IMyType> All() {
  var query = _connection.Query("SELECT * FROM [table]");
  return query.Select(o => (IMyType) _myTypeFactory.Create(o));
}
```

It doesn't currently work because there's simply no implicit conversion available between `IEnumerable<dynamic>` and `IEnumerable<IMyType>`. `IEnumerable<dynamic>` could be implemented in any number of ways, and given that *each item will be generated dynamically* there's no reason to suppose the result value will implement `IEnumerable<IMyType>`.

I agree that it *looks* like the second form isn't actually adding anything, but the compiler doesn't check all the *possible* return types of `_myTypeFactory.Create(o)` - it treats that whole expression as a dynamic value, i.e. the expression is of type `dynamic`. Therefore the `Select` result is still of type `IEnumerable<dynamic>`.

Another option is to specify the generic type argument to `Select`.

```
public IEnumerable<IMyType> All() {
  var query = _connection.Query("SELECT * FROM [table]");
  return query.Select<IMyType>(o => _myTypeFactory.Create(o));
}
```

That's attempting to force the lambda expression to a `Func<dynamic, IMyType>` - I *believe* that will work...

EDIT: As noted in comments, forcing the method invocation to be resolved at compile-time will fix it too. Basically it depends what you find most readable.

Comment: @Hellfire: I'm glad it makes sense to you - it took me a few attempts to work it out myself :)

Comment: Thanks Jon.  Once you explain it, it makes perfect sense. Casting does indeed work and is pretty enough for my purposes. The third option does not.

Comment: The casting to `IMyType` is a red hering though, you don't actually need to dynamically invoke `MyTypeFactory.Create(dynamic o)` in this case. You only need it for accessing the properties which is done inside of `Create`.

Comment: @jbtule: It's not really a red herring - it's just an alternative. I agree that either the call can be made non-dynamic or the result can be cast - either will work fine.

Comment: @jon-skeet, let me put it a different way. Dapper is using dynamic because it's properties are determined at runtime, it has dynamic behavior. It is Dapper's declaration of dynamic which is causing `Create` to be invoked dynamically, but there's nothing new to be discovered at runtime, and it clearly wasn't the intent given the question. Adding a cast to the interface makes the code work, but if the intent is not for dynamic behavior does that make sense?

Comment: @jbtule: I agree that there's no particular benefit to letting the `Create` be invoked dynamically - unless the OP finds that to be the most readable of the many solutions. It would perform slightly better to make all of this less dynamic, of course, but I think the readability is the more important goal. It's possible that leaving the Create call dynamic will allow for more readable Create calls later (more overloads). Basically there's a huge amount of choice available here :)

Answer (score 1):

The best fix is probably to remove the dynamic invocation from the select statement then you'll get your expected static type `IEnumerable<IMyType>`.

```
public IEnumerable<IMyType> All() {
  var query = _connection.Query("SELECT * FROM [table]");
  return query.Select(o => _myTypeFactory.Create((Object)o)); //cast dynamic type to Object
}
```

**OR**

```
public IEnumerable<IMyType> All() {
      IEnumerable<object> query = _connection.Query("SELECT * FROM [table]"); //IEnumerable<dynamic> is the same as IEnumerable<object>
      return query.Select(o => _myTypeFactory.Create(o)); 
}
```